# Android Child Activity Not Linking to Other Child Activities

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, onclicklistener

I'm able to open children activities from the parent MainActivity.java file, however, I cannot open a child activity from another child activity. For instance, I am wanting to basically have a main page that allows you to go from page to page in the child activity almost like a story. I have tried using intents with an on click listener such as this below:

```
TextView backBtn = findViewById(R.id.backButton);

    // Create onClickListener
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bloodActivity = new Intent(SinActivity.this, BloodActivity.class);
            startActivity(bloodActivity);
        }
    });
```

I also have tried using the finish(); in the onClick method, however, it won't terminate the current child activity to even go back to the MainActivity.java file. Below I am posting a link to the GitHub repository if more visualization is needed. I appreciate any help I can get with this.

https://github.com/uenvymenow/EvangelismApp/tree/master/app/src/main

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want. I Guess you mean (main > A > B > C) and i press backBtn whatever i was always go back to main? more detail plz

Comment: @nikeru8 correct. Basically I have the MainActicity and then child activities A, B and C that they can route back to the MainActivity when getting the back button or navigate to another activity if clicking continue. For instance on activity A, user clicks continue and can go to activity B, then on activity B they press the backbtn to go back to MainActivity.

Comment: I cannot open a child activity from another child activity--> are you getting any error

Comment: @JyotiJK unfortunately it's not giving any error. Everything compiles appropriately but when clicking the Textview or Button it doesn't switch to requested activity.

Comment: can you post your full exception stacktrace

Comment: is backBtn Button or TextView?

Comment: @JyotiJK Here is the stacktrace that I'm getting. It doesn't do anything after hitting the back TextView
[link](https://github.com/uenvymenow/EvangelismApp/blob/master/Stacktrace.txt)

Comment: remove Log.d("EvangelismApp", Log.getStackTraceString(new Exception()));

Comment: I was asking about the exception which you got when you click textview

Comment: I'm brand new to learning programming so not exactly sure how I can provide this information. I thought it would be from the Logcat with the Log call but I don't believe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your project and find your problem.

Following blow:

```
 TextView backBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.backTextView);
    backBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

    TextView continueTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.continueTextView);
    continueTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent bloodActivity = new Intent(SinActivity.this, BloodActivity.class);
            startActivity(bloodActivity);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

**but**

your Listener is not a problem that **TextViewBtn** is under ScrollView make user can not click your **TextViewBtn**.

Try to fix your layout **activity_sin.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.aaron.evangelismapp.SinActivity">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sinWordTextView"
            style="@style/sinHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/sinHeader" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sinScriptureTextView"
            style="@style/sinScripture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sinImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/backTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/backText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continueTextView"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/continueText" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it help.

Comment: I did just try this and that worked. I'm fairly new at programming so wasn't sure how the heirarchy worked with those types of views but makes sense that the ScrollView was overlapping the LinearLayout. Thank you and much appreciated.